# I want to add a JSONObject to a JSONArray and that JSONArray included in other JSONObject

Tags: json, arrays

I need below kind of structure constructed in java and send it as response :

```java
var abc = {
  "action": "Remove",
  "datatable": [
    { "userid": "userid0", "username": "name0" },
    { "userid": "userid1", "username": "name1" },
    { "userid": "userid2", "username": "name2" },
    { "userid": "userid3", "username": "name3" }
  ],
  "msgType": "success"
};
```

I am doing:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

for (loop) {
    JSONObject jsonObj= new JSONObject();
    jsonObj.put("srcOfPhoto", srcOfPhoto);
    jsonObj.put("username", "name"+count);
    jsonObj.put("userid", "userid"+count);

    jsonArray.add(jsonObj.toJSONString());
}

Map paramMap = new HashMap();

paramMap.put("action", "remove");

paramMap.put("datatable", jsonArray );

paramMap.put(Constant.MSG_TYPE , Constant.SUCCESS);

getJSONMessage(paramMap);
```

and here above function is converting paramMap into json string like:

```
public static String getJSONMessage(Map<String, String> paramMap) {
    if (paramMap != null && paramMap.size() > 0)
        return JSONObject.toJSONString(paramMap);
    else
        return "";
}
```

but it is not creating the right structure, can anybody help me in this?

here is what I am getting output:

```
{"action":"Remove","datatable":[{\"userid\":\"userid0\",\"srcOfPhoto\":\"users\\\/JMMBGTCHG.jpg\",\"username\":\"name0\"}"],"msgType":"success"}
```

which is not being parsed in javascript.

```
var json = eval('(' + respText+')');
alert("contents>>"+json.datatable);
alert("contents.datatable[0]>>>"+json.datatable[0].username);
```

last alert showing undefined.

---

ohh sorry I forgot to paste last line , here is the last line:

```
getJSONMessage(paramMap);
```

and above function is converting paramMap into json string:

```
public static String getJSONMessage(Map<String, String> paramMap){
    if(paramMap != null && paramMap.size() > 0)
        return JSONObject.toJSONString(paramMap);
    else
        return "";
}
```

Comment: I've merged your two accounts together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/1228) Also, StackOverflow isn't a forum; if you have a new question, please ask a new question. If you want to include more information in your question, please [edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7497980/edit). If you want to interact with one of the people who has answered, you can leave them a comment.

Answer (score 32):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

for (loop) {
    JSONObject jsonObj= new JSONObject();
    jsonObj.put("srcOfPhoto", srcOfPhoto);
    jsonObj.put("username", "name"+count);
    jsonObj.put("userid", "userid"+count);

    jsonArray.put(jsonObj.valueToString());
}

JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();

parameters.put("action", "remove");

parameters.put("datatable", jsonArray );

parameters.put(Constant.MSG_TYPE , Constant.SUCCESS);
```

Why were you using an Hashmap if what you wanted was to put it into a JSONObject?

EDIT: As per http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html

EDIT2: On the JSONObject method used, I'm following the code available at: https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java#L2327 , that method is not deprecated.

We're storing a string representation of the JSONObject, not the JSONObject itself

Comment: there's no `add(jsonObj)`, but `put(jsonObj)` is possible (it doesn't seem necesary to convert to JSONString either)

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere:There is add method:

Comment: The method toJSONString() is undefined for the type JSONObject ??

Comment: it appears that the standard changed to `valueToString()` will edit.

Comment: There is no push() method in jsonArray object.

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONArray successObject=new JSONArray();
JSONObject dataObject=new JSONObject();
successObject.put(dataObject.toString());
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("fromZIPCode","123456"); 

JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject();
json1.put("fromZIPCode","123456"); 
       sList.add(json1);
       sList.add(json);

System.out.println(sList);

Output will be

[{"fromZIPCode":"123456"},{"fromZIPCode":"123456"}]
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: This is totally unrelated to the questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.JsonArray;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class WriteJsonArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("action","Remove");
        jsonObject.addProperty("msgType","success");


        JsonObject item1 = new JsonObject();
        item1.addProperty("userid", "userid0");
        item1.addProperty("username","name0");

        JsonObject item2 = new JsonObject();
        item2.addProperty("userid", "userid1");
        item2.addProperty("username","name1");

        JsonObject item3 = new JsonObject();
        item3.addProperty("userid", "userid2");
        item3.addProperty("username","name2");

        JsonObject item4 = new JsonObject();
        item4.addProperty("userid", "userid3");
        item4.addProperty("username","name3");

        JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
        jsonArray.add(item1);
        jsonArray.add(item2);
        jsonArray.add(item3);
        jsonArray.add(item4);
        jsonObject.add("datatable", jsonArray);

        System.out.println("Result: \n" + jsonObject.toString());

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
org.json.simple.JSONArray resultantJson = new org.json.simple.JSONArray();

        org.json.JSONArray o1 = new org.json.JSONArray("[{\"one\":[],\"two\":\"abc\"}]");
        org.json.JSONArray o2 = new org.json.JSONArray("[{\"three\":[1,2],\"four\":\"def\"}]");


        resultantJson.addAll(o1.toList());
        resultantJson.addAll(o2.toList());
```

Comment: Please try to explain why you think this code would solve the problem.